# Vanilla JavaScript, interact with a single DOM element which is part of a class group without affecting the others of the group

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a number of items (clouds in this case) that once reached the rightmost side of the browser, thir position is reset to 0 (leftmost side of the screen) or less and the loop should continue.
Each cloud's position should be reset independently from the others, but in my case what is happening is that everytime a cloud reaches the target, they all get reset and I can't figure out why.

I have a series of DOM elements:

```
<div class="cloud" id="c1"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c2"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c3"></div>
```

In my JS file I have an array containing all 3 DOM elements:

```
var clouds = document.querySelectorAll(".cloud");
```

I have first loop to setup some css attributes:

```
for(let i=0; i < clouds.length; ++i){
  setUp(clouds[i]);
  }

function setUp(item){
  item.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)`;
}
```

And then I loop through it running this method:

```
function increment(item){
   let xVal = Number(item.style.transform.split('px')[0].split('(')[1]);
   let newVal = xVal >= window.innerWidth ? 0 : xVal + 1;

   item.style.transform = `translate3d(${newVal}px, 0px, 0px)`;
   item.style.background = 'red';
}


setInterval(function(){
   clouds.forEach(increment);
},700)
```

**CORRECTION:**
As pointed out by @AlexWayne, it was a minor issue that was solved by separating the positions of the items in the setUp function.
In the form of:

```
item.style.transform = `translate3d(${i * 100}px, 0px, 0px)`;
```

as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/36m1oatv/14/ .
  Although it is strange the reason why a similar version as the following
https://jsfiddle.net/kwucnht9/1/ doesn't work.

Comment: Your script looks as if its not filtering the nodes to track each individual one and there position.  It's just executing the increment style uniformly against all available nodes.

Comment: @StevenVanSant How would I filter the nodes the way you are saying?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] because I did and I cannot replicate this at all: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/36m1oatv/ (I fixed the `xVal` assignment since it added `1` to a string, which resulted in the position going from 1 to 11, then 111, then 1111)

Comment: Maybe you should set their initial positions randomly, so they don't all start at the same place?

Comment: Or make the increments random for each cloud.

Comment: It seems to work just fine if you have them start in different positions https://jsfiddle.net/36m1oatv/14/

Comment: @ChrisG oh yes, sorry, just fixed.
Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/kwucnht9/

Comment: @AlexWayne I don't know how you did it, but it seems to be working. I will study your code to better understand if it is actually what I was expecting.

Comment: @AlexWayne I'm actually speechless about your sorchery... in my original version, same as here https://jsfiddle.net/kwucnht9/ they actually start at different positions, but still reset all together.
How come?

Comment: @Denjous You are placing the clouds at different positions using fixed `left:` values. Then you use `transform3d` to move them. This means that a) checking the transform x coordinate against `window.innerWidth` makes no sense and b) therefore every cloud will move back at the exact same point, regardless of their actual position (left + transform x) since the transform x is the same for all of them.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ahL0b9jv/

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!
I figured you might like a pure CSS solution since most things you are doing in your javascript was manipulating the css anyway.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

```css
@keyframes example {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100vh);
    }
}

.cloud {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.cloud:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: tomato;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.cloud:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: hotpink;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.cloud:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: greenyellow;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud" id="c1"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c2"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, though I was looking for a JS version.

Comment: Care to explain why? Do you plan in triggering more stuff once a cloud reached the end of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your clouds all reset at the same time is because each cloud is being transformed identically each time.

```
function setUp(item) {
    item.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)`; // set all clouds to 0 on the x-axis.
}

setInterval(function(){
   clouds.forEach(increment); // Every 700ms, shift each cloud along the x-axis by 1px.  
},700)
```

Because your initial offset positioning is set identically by `setUp`, the `translate3d(${newVal}px, 0px, 0px)` is identical for all clouds. If you were to change `setUp` so that each cloud is transformed on the x-axis by a different initial amount then your routine would work.

```js
(function() {
    var clouds = document.querySelectorAll(".cloud");

    for (let i = 0; i < clouds.length; ++i) {
      setUp(clouds[i]);
    }

    function setUp(item) {
      var rando = Math.random() * 250; // set a random spot between 0 and 250px.
      item.style.transform = `translate3d(${rando}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    }

    function increment(item) {
      let xVal = Number(item.style.transform.split('px')[0].split('(')[1]);
      let newVal = xVal >= window.innerWidth/3 ? 0 : xVal + 5;

      item.style.transform = `translate3d(${newVal}px, 0px, 0px)`;
      item.style.background = 'red';
    }


    setInterval(function() {
      clouds.forEach(increment);
    }, 100)
})();
```

```css
.cloud {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.cloud:nth-child(0){
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 80px;
}


.cloud:nth-child(1){
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 206px;
}

.cloud:nth-child(2){
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud" id="c1"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c2"></div>
<div class="cloud" id="c3"></div>
```

The reason your clouds won't snap back to the left edge is because you have the left edge positioned absolutely, so they only reset to their normal, non-offset, positions.